# C++ via Visual Studio Video - "Include file not found in browse.path." C/C++ [1, 1]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have read numerous examples and videos to learn how to fix this to no avail. I am new to using Visual Studio Code and I seem to not be able to resolve this issue independently. I've reset my settings, deleted and reinstalled, etc. One common occurrence I am seeing is to access "MingGW", which I apparently do not have installed on my computer and/or have access to. I am in need of great assistance!

Comment: If you don't have a C++ compiler how are you going to run a C++ program? Install one of the many C++ compilers and use that.

Comment: As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Point is, we don't know what you did and what you tried and all we got is that snippet from some error message you got somewhere. That's by far too little info!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the error is related to the fact that you don't have a compiler installed on your machine (or VS Code can't find its directory).

You can download the compiler from its official website here:
[Mingw-w64](https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question ""MingGW", which I apparently do not have installed on my computer and/or have access to"

Install MingGw, and then compile.

Here is a [Link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) to help you get started on setting up the MinGW for Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are also new to C++. Are you on Windows? (I will assume so since you explicitly mentioned MinGW).

- MinGW is an older version of the compiler, and I would encourage you to install the official Microsoft Sdk instead - that is, if you want the easy road.
- Are you using Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? They are two very different application, and if you are new to either programming or C++ I would heartily recommend Visual Studio as it does all the "complicated things" for you.
- There is a difference between installing Visual Studio Code (a text editor) and a compiler (MinGW, MSVC++, clang, GCC, Intel, etc.).

Btw., I know your pain - we have all been there! Don't expect things to be easy in programming, it takes some time. This is especially true for C++ which has more complications than other languages (but worth the effort!).